# qTranslate and Wordpress functions

Tags: qtranslate

I'm using qTranslate on a Wordpress site but am having a little trouble working some bits of it into the Wordpress functions in some cases. For example, when I want to include a "Read More link" within a query, I can just do:

```
echo _e('[:en]Read More_[:ru]читать далее_');
```

(that said, it looks like it's echoing an echo, so I may not be doing that right, even though it seems to work).

But I can't quite work out the syntax for this:

```
echo comments_number( '<div class="noComment"></div>No Comments', '<div class="oneComment"></div>One Comment', '<div class="oneComment"></div>% Comments' );
```

How do I put in the translation for those?

Comment: Though you have found the solution already. But `_e` function itself echos. You would echo if its `__()` version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
echo comments_number(
    qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage('<div class="noComment"></div>[:en]No Comments[:es]No comentarios'), 
    qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage('<div class="oneComment"></div>[:en]One Comment[:es]Uno comentario'), 
    qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage('<div class="oneComment"></div>[:en]% Comments[:es]% comentarios)' 
);
```

Comment: Fab. Although it doesn't work quite the way you've done it. I tried it this way: [:en] rather than wrapping it in [lang_en][/lang_en] and it works. Cheers!